# Activación de ambiente virtual de Python falla silenciosamente

Tags: python, rutas, virtualenv

Creé un ambiente virtual usando `python -m venv venv` en la carpeta de mi proyecto.

Al activarlo con `venv\Scripts\activate` el `prompt` se actualiza al familiar...

```
(venv) D:\mi_dir\mi_proyecto>
```

... pero cuando hago el `where python`, no aparece la ruta del *Python* de mi `venv`, sólo aparece el del ambiente `root` de *Anaconda*.

¿Cómo debo crear y/o activar el `venv` para poder usarlo?

Comment: Si tu respuesta pudo solucionar el problema puedes marcarla como correcta, o dentro de las 48 horas luego de haberla formulado. De lo contrario puedes esperar a que alguien responda de mejor manera y marcarla como correcta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En mi caso el *path* del proyecto tenía tildes. Lo moví a una carpeta cuya ruta no tuviera tildes y me funcionó.

Comment: Que informacion adicional hace falta para considerar esta una respuesta una respuesta completa? Estoy haciendo evidente los pasos que resolvieron mi problema particular.

Comment: Vi la pregunta y pensé que era un comentario de otra persona, porque **en la pregunta la ruta no está con tildes**.